# Web scraping through proxies

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, server, web-crawler, bots

I am currently using a web scraping tool (Octoparse) to extract out information from some websites. Previously, I was able to use proxies to extract out the information. I couldn't use my own IP address as after extracting a few items I would be blocked out. Recently, the website seems to have blocked proxies from accessing the site (see screenshot below). I can certainly find other websites but they don't happen to be as good as this one. May I know if there is a way around this?

[image: Access denied :(]

PS: I am a student and just want to extract out information to make flash cards for studying and do not have any ill intent.

Comment: This is a very hard problem. Depending on the type of protections, you are probably out of luck. There are so many things that you would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you mentioned Octoparse. As far as I know, Octoparse provides IP proxies. However, it is quite different to use the IP proxy in different edition. You should manually add the IP proxies you had in the text box while if you use the standard edition or the professional edition, Octoparse will provide more than 500 third party proxies for automatic IP rotation. Therefore, I would recommend you use the standard edition if you don't have the IP proxy yourself. If you want to learn more, you could follow the tutorial [Use Proxy Servers for Anonymous Web Scraping](http://www.octoparse.com/tutorial/use-proxy-servers-for-anonymous-web-scraping/) to learn more.